# ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS -- apps-menu ("applications") extension opens correctly but then immediately closes

Tags: gnome, firefox

(This is a crosspost from https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/-/issues/449 but posts seem to go unanswered for months over there so I'm trying here instead.)

The problem is that I'm getting strange behavior from apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com version 51.
As described in the title, what happens is, when I click on the 'applications' button (either in the top bar or when using the dash-to-panel extension), the menu opens, but then after a few seconds of moving the cursor over the menu, the menu closes again.

Possibly relevant:
I've also noticed that dconf fails to list the apps-menu extension in org.gnome.shell.extensions although all of the other extensions are shown correctly, and the apps-menu extension is in fact present in the ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions folder.

I've tried disabling, removing, purging and reinstalling everything I can think of, including the gnome desktop, browser extensions (I'm using the non-snap firefox 115.0.2 64 bit) and extension manager, and gnome tweaks, but I always end up back with the exact same problem.

I also found this Mate page https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/upgraded-to-20-04-and-the-menu-keeps-closing/21781 which talks about 'brisk' menus(!!?), which sounds very similar to my issue, but I don't know how or if that might apply in this case?

Anyway, any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Gnome 42.9
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
X11
(Snap has been entirely removed from this installation)

Added information as requested:

The extension is called Applications Menu and its internal name is apps-menu.

This is the extension's webpage, which it shares with other extensions -- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions

Comment: Please indicate what Gnome Shell extension you are talking about - provide link to its webpage

Comment: Additional info provided as requested.